Old Black & White movie about a 13th floor in a building
When I was a kid I saw a old black & white movie that was kind of a thriller/suspense/twilight zonie type. I was about a 13th floor in a building that most in the movie did not know existed. It had a man and a woman as main characters. From what I remember they were being chased. It was a long time ago so I don't remember much about it. Not sure if it was a full length movie or not. I saw it on television on a Saturday afternoon in 1985 (approx). Just wondering if any out there remembers this!

How about Mirage (1965)?  Black-and-white noir movie with Gregory Peck as someone who realizes he has amnesia and is trying to retrace his steps.  At one point he is told there is no 13th floor, but later there is a key to the 13th floor.  There are people chasing them.
